# Return monthly sales value in Django

Tags: django

I've got some simple models below

```
class Stamping(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Product(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_product')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    price = models.FloatField()

class GroupProductOrder(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_product_orders')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Order(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    fulfilled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(GroupProductOrder, blank=True)

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        cost = 0
        for product in self.products.all():
            cost += product.total_price
        return cost
```

Now I want to query the database and return some details on a monthly basis. Details like total number of sales for each month and **sum** of sales for each month.
I've tried using annotate but it seems can't pass model property in it. What is the best way to tackle this problem?
Example of expected output is `{'month': 'October', 'count': 5, 'total': 15}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query and annotate with the following statement:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth

output = (
    Order.objects
    .annotate(
        month=ExtractMonth("created")
    )
    .values("month")
    .annotate(
        count=Sum("products__quantity"),
        total=Sum(
            F("products__quantity") * F("products__product__price"),
            output_field=FloatField()
        )
    )
    .order_by("month")
)
```